# How can service run as a logged in user?

Tags: c#, windows, service, windows-services, exploit

I'm trying to find out if it's possible for a service to run under the logged in user account. The reason why I'm trying to figure out whether it's possible is because we have, during a penetration test, discovered a service with an [unquoted service path](https://medium.com/@SumitVerma101/windows-privilege-escalation-part-1-unquoted-service-path-c7a011a8d8ae) that was listed as having Local System rights. We have then replaced the service binary in the unquoted path  with a binary that should add a user, but the new binary was started only with the rights and running as the logged in user.

We are trying to investigate what could have happened, because we are fairly confident that the binary should have been started with Local System rights.

Since I am unfamiliar with Services and how do they and their rights actually work, I'm trying to replicate the situation so we can explain why the exploit did not work and how to avoid making the same mistake in the future, which means that I need to set up a service that would appear to be local system, but eventually run under loged in user.

I tried looking up some tutorials about how to write services, and found this property to be close to what I want:

```
 this.serviceProcessInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller();
        this.serviceInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller();
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.User;
```

However, in the documentation of ServiceAccount.User option, it specifies that

> An account defined by a specific user on the network. Specifying User for the Account member causes the system to **prompt for a valid user name and password** when the service is installed, unless you set values for both the Username and Password properties of your ServiceProcessInstaller instance.

Since the service is on a corporate laptop, I doubt that it has been created using this method of having to enter every specific user credentials, so there has to be some other way. Is there anyone here familiar with the development of Services that could explain what could have happened, and if it's possible for a service to have the rights of currently logged in user without requiring credentials of each user? I'm sure it's a fairly common problem, but I did not manage to find a way how to do it.

I have found several ways how to have a LocalSystem service start another program under the logged in user, but since I'm replacing the service initial binary, it should have the correct rights anyway.

Unfortunately, we no longer have access to the device and can not verify whether we have only misread the Account of the service, and it has been set to the user the whole time. But we are fairly certain that the service had Local System rights, and we would love to expand our knowledge of services and figure out what has happened. I don't think I've ever seen a service with User in LogOnAs though.

Thank you for any kind of answer!

Comment: Services generally start before any user is logged on.  Who is the "logged on user" in that case?  Windows can support multiple users at a time, which one do you pick?  If you log off for the weekend and log back on on Monday, do you care that there is no "Logged on User". Unless there is a _really_ good reason, services should not run as Local System.  Local system is just that - your services run with the rights that Windows uses to run your system (slightly more than admin rights). If you have a vulnerability, then the bad guy gets to do anything he wants on the box. Look up _Local Service_

Comment: @Flydog57 It is possible that someone hard-coded their own credentials into the service installer. It's unlikely, and horrifying if it was done, but it is possible. That would explain how it happened without a user being prompted when the service is installed. You can find out by examining the source code. If the code isn't available, and it's a .NET service, run it through a decompiler.

Comment: Yeah, installing a service as a particular user is (/was) pretty common.  That way you could tune the permissions on the account to have the minimal set the service needed.  The downside was password management (and hiding).  With the advent of _Service User Accounts_ (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/service-user-accounts and Group Managed Accounts, you shouldn't need to do this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/group-managed-service-accounts/group-managed-service-accounts-overview